# Given date or greater than system date validation in MySQL (sample query given)

Tags: mysql

I need to add a where condition something like this below:

```
where future_date='12/31/9999 12:59:59' or future_date > current system date
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) Date and Time Functions

```
where future_date='12/31/9999 12:59:59' 
or future_date > NOW()
```